# Is std::remove_if guaranteed to call predicate in order?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm, erase-remove-idiom

Will std::remove_if always call the predicate on each element in order (according to the iterator's order) or could it be called out of order?

Here is a toy example of what I would like to do:

```
void processVector(std::vector<int> values)
{
    values.erase(std::remove_if(values.begin(), values.end(), [](int v)
    {
        if (v % 2 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << v << "\n";
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }));
}
```

I need to process and remove all elements of a vector that meet certain criteria, and erase + remove_if seems perfect for that.  However, the processing I will do has side effects, and I need to make sure that processing happens in order (in the toy example, suppose that I want to print the values in the order they appear in the original vector).

Is it safe to assume that my predicate will be called on each item in order?

I assume that C++17's execution policies would disambiguate this, but since C++17 isn't out yet that obviously doesn't help me.

Edit: Also, is this a good idea?  Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: To be clear, would the side-effects alter the `vector` itself? That would invalidate the iterators being used in any event, so it's good to make sure of that first. I'd also be wary of any side-effects that could affect the _values_ in the `vector`, since during execution of `remove_if`, the exact location of any given item in the `vector` is not guaranteed.

Comment: No, the side effects would not alter the vector.  The side effects are actually writing some things to a file.

Comment: I think weather or not it does is moot.  Do all of the side effects, then do the remove.

Comment: No, there's no such guarantee.

Comment: Answer: make processing not have side effects. Do those separate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard makes no guarantees on the order of calling the predicate.

What you ought to use is [`stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition). You partition the sequence based on your predicate. Then you can walk the partitioned sequence to perform whatever "side effect" you wanted to do, since `stable_partition` ensures the relative order of both sets of data. Then you can erase the elements from the `vector`.

`stable_partition` has to be used here because `erase_if` leaves the contents of the "erased" elements undefined.

In code:

```
void processVector(std::vector<int> &values)
{
    auto it = std::stable_partition(begin(values), end(values), [](int v) {return v % 2 != 0;});

    std::for_each(it, end(values), [](int v) {std::cout << v << "\n";});

    values.erase(it, end(values));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I reread the question to doublecheck myself, then deleted the comment. Still: Why not simply do `erase_if`, followed by a `for_each`?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Because `erase_if` does not guarantee that it *moves* anything to the "empty" slots at the end of the range. `stable_partition` does.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but here's my take:

While the order is not specified, it will involve jumping through hoops to implement an order different from first-to-last, due to the following:

- The complexity is specified to be "exactly `std::distance(first, last)` applications of the predicate", which requires visiting each element exactly once.
- The iterators are `ForwardIterator`s, which means that they can only be incremented.
- [C++17 and above] To prevent parallel processing, one can use the version that accepts an execution policy, and pass `std::execution::seq`.

Given the above, I believe that a (non-parallel) implementation that follows a different order will be convoluted and have no advantages over the straightforward case.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Answer (score -2):

They *should* be processed in order, but it is not *guaranteed*.

`std::remove_if()` moves "removed" items to the end of the container, they are not actually removed from the container until `erase()` is called.  Both operations will potentially invalidate existing iterators in a `std::vector`.

Comment: Where in the standard does it guarantee in-order processing?

Comment: @DafangCao: yeah. My bad. Forgot that `erase` doesn't guarantee anything in the second "partition", which allows it to use a simpler algorithm.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I did not say it was *guaranteed* to be processed in order, I said it *should* be processed in order (see the "Possible implementation" on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)). However, the standard does say this for `remove_if()` in § 25.3.8: "*Complexity: Exactly `last - first` applications of the corresponding predicate.*" So it can't pass an item to the predicate more than once (like a sort can). But I guess that does not prevent the algorithm from working last-to-first instead of first-to-last, though the latter is more likely.